# Can you create SSIS packages with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

Is it possible to create a new SSIS package with just T-SQL?

Specificity I am using SQL Server 2016, I haven't done a lot with SSIS yet.

Comment: This tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917(v=sql.130).aspx) will take you through the steps of creating your first SSIS package.
This series of articles (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) will show you many more techniques.

Comment: Depends on what you mean.   It might be possible, but no sane person would want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Some of the elements in an SSIS package cannot be expressed by TSQL. You can build packages programmatically using C# or VB (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345167.aspx) but not TSQL. However, once built, you can use the package by itself or add it as part of one of some SQL Agent job step using TSQL ([creating job with ssis step using tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565988/creating-job-with-ssis-step-using-tsql)).

Comment: If we're mentioning tools that can generate SSIS packages dynamically, [BIML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Markup_Language) is apparently what the cool kids are using.